# enable to see firebase error console log

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm connecting to firebase from a android app. My app is supposed to be writing data to my firebase, but it isn't. I'm also not seeing any errors, warnings, etc. logged to the console. So how do I crank up logging for the firebase to see what's actually going on? Does such a thing exist? I tried searching the firebase API docs, but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errors will be logged automatically.

You can get more verbose logging from the Firebase Database by calling:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG);
```